# glDrawElements only draws first triangle specified by indices

Tags: c++, opengl

I just started learning OpenGL and I am having some trouble with glDrawElements. I am trying to draw two triangles using glDrawElements with GL_TRIANGLE, but only one triangle appears.

**What is expected**: glDrawElements draw two triangles with vertices

(0,0) (1,1) (-1,1) and (0,0) (-1,-1) (1,-1)

**What happens**: glDrawElements draw one triangle with vertices (0,0) (1,1) (-1,1)

Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Sample code does not display two triangles", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewInit();

    GLfloat vertices[] {
        +0.0f, +0.0f, //0
        +1.0f, +1.0f, //1
        -1.0f, +1.0f, //2
        -1.0f, -1.0f  //3
        +1.0f, -1.0f  //4
    };

    GLuint vertexBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    GLuint indexBufferID;
    GLushort indices[] {0,1,2, 0,3,4};
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

This sample opens a 640x480 GLFW window, displays a triangle with vertices in both upper corners and the third vertex in the middle of the window. The other triangle, with vertices in both bottom corners and the third vertex in the middle, is missing. Why is that?

Specs:

**OS**: Linux Mint 17

**GPU**: nVidia GTX 275

**GPU driver**: 331.67

**GLEW version**: 1.10.0

**GLFW version**: 3.0.4

Comment: `glDrawElements` doesn't use an index buffer. You have to pass in the `indices` pointer as the last parameter instead of 0.

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced: I was also going to start my comment with "what?", but genpfault beat me to it. Of course it uses index buffers. How else would you use index buffers?

Comment: Just one (probably dumb) question: aren't we supposed to always write shaders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Commas are important.  This:

```
GLfloat vertices[] =
{
    +0.0f, +0.0f, //0
    +1.0f, +1.0f, //1
    -1.0f, +1.0f, //2
    -1.0f, -1.0f  //3
    +1.0f, -1.0f  //4
};
size_t elements = sizeof( vertices ) / sizeof( GLfloat ) = 9(!)
```

is not the same as this:

```
GLfloat vertices[] =
{
    +0.0f, +0.0f, //0
    +1.0f, +1.0f, //1
    -1.0f, +1.0f, //2
    -1.0f, -1.0f, //3
    +1.0f, -1.0f  //4
};
size_t elements = sizeof( vertices ) / sizeof( GLfloat ) = 10
```

Note the added comma at the end of line `3`.

If `vertices` only has `9` elements then when `glDrawElements()` goes to try to read the fifth vertex only the X coordinate will be valid.  The Y coordinate will contain garbage if you're lucky, a segfault if you're not.

Also, you shouldn't use the generic vertex attribute functions without specifying some shaders.

All together:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Sample code does not display two triangles", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewInit();

    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        +0.0f, +0.0f, //0
        +1.0f, +1.0f, //1
        -1.0f, +1.0f, //2
        -1.0f, -1.0f, //3
        +1.0f, -1.0f, //4
    };

    GLuint vertexBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0 );

    GLuint indexBufferID;
    GLushort indices[] = { 0,1,2, 0,3,4 };
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just found the missing comma as you posted, it was the problem. Thank you for solid answer.

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but I made a _very_ similar mistake with brand new code... I'm speechless... [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132402/should-there-be-any-behavioural-differece-in-behaviour-for-vbo-vs-immediate-mode/36132920#36132920)